# Is this identity provable?

Tags: trigonometry

I was given this question by a friend but it seems the question is not correctly phrased in the book that he got it.

$ \frac{\cos A}{1-\tan A} +\frac{\sin A}{1-\cot A}=\sin A +\cos A$

Is the above identity provable?

Comment: What makes you think "is not correctly phrased" ?

Comment: @DOCTORNGILAZIBANDAJOSHUA Please don't type in ALL CAPS, it seems like you are yelling.

Comment: What an ABSURD TITLE...! "Is the identity provable?" Of course the identity IS provable – if one says an equality is an identity, it must be proved, hence is provable. If an equality is not proven, one COULD NOT call it an 'identity'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take left hand side 
$$\color{blue}{\frac{\cos A}{1-\tan A}+\frac{\sin A}{1-\cot A}}$$ $$=\frac{\cos A}{1-\frac{\sin A}{\cos A}}+\frac{\sin A}{1-\frac{\cos A}{\sin A}}$$
$$=\frac{\cos^2 A}{\cos A-\sin A}+\frac{\sin^2 A}{\sin A-\cos A}$$
$$=\frac{\cos^2 A}{\cos A-\sin A}-\frac{\sin^2 A}{\cos A-\sin A}$$
$$=\frac{\cos^2 A-\sin^2 A}{\cos A-\sin A}$$
$$=\frac{(\cos A+\sin A)(\cos A-\sin A)}{\cos A-\sin A}=\cos A+\sin A$$
$$\color{blue}{=\sin A+\cos A}$$

Hence, the trigonometric identity is correct & provable.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct.

Use these identities: $\tan A=\frac{\sin A}{\cos A},\cot A=\frac{\cos A}{\sin A}$; then multiply and divide it with $\sin A+\cos  A$, use $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\cos^2 A}{\left(\cos A-\sin A\right)}+\frac{\sin^2A}{\left(\sin A-\cos A\right)}$$ is true by factorizing $\frac{1}{(\cos A-\sin A)}$

Comment: You may want to add more detail. Also, you wrote an expression, not a statement, so it cannot be "true."

Answer (score 0):

it is an identity. here is one way to prove it:
$$\frac{\cos t }{1- \tan t} + \frac{\sin t}{1 - \cot t} =\frac{\cos^2 t}{\cos t - \sin t} + \frac{\sin^2 t }{\sin t - \cos t} = \frac{\cos^2 t - \sin^2 t}{\cos t - \sin t} = \cos t + \sin t.  $$